# Doctrine - ManyToMany with table as target

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm, annotations

Is it possible in Doctrine to create a ManyToMany (unidirectional) relationship with a table as the targetEntity?

I have the following **database** constellation:
A *job* and a *service* table which are connected via Doctrine ManyToMany (join table is called *service2job*), because a job can have several services and same services can appear in different jobs.
Now there is a table *employee*. An employee can do some services that are depending on a job.

And here's the tricky one: one or more employees can work on the same service depending on an job.
So I need another join table which connects service2job and employee (*emp2ser2job*) which should be generated by Doctrine.

The **Doctrine/Symfony** side:
Services of a Job are saved as *ArrayCollection* in the *Job* class. Services and Jobs are connected via Doctrine ManyToMany (Annotation).

I want to save the services, depending on an job and done by an employee, in the *Employee* class.
But here the problem: To do that I need to refer the ManyToMany relationship in Employee to the table service2job, because I don't want to create a class Service2Job that I just need to refer on.

Is there any possibility to do that without creating a class (Emp2Ser2Job) just for mapping and as entity to refer on?

**Code:**

```
// Service
class Service 
{
  private $id;
}

// Job
...
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
...

class Job 
{
   public function __construct() 
   {
     $this->services = new ArrayCollection();
   }
   /**
   * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="KuMiV\ServicesBundle\Entity\Service")
     // table that should be targetEntity in Employee ($services);
   * @ORM\JoinTable(name="service2job",
   *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="job_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
   *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="service_id",  referencedColumnName="id")}
   *      )
   **/
   private $services;
   ...
}

// Employee
class Employee 
{
   public function __construct() 
   {
     $this->services = new ArrayCollection();
   }

   /**
   * @ORM\ManyToMany //how should annotation be here to make a ManyToMany unidirectional to the table service2job?
   * @ORM\JoinTable(name="employee2service2job",
   *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="employee_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
   *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="job_id", referencedColumnName="job_id"), @ORM\JoinColumn(name="service_id", referencedColumnName="service_id")}
   *      )
   **/
   private $services;
}
```

Comment: I would just create something like a `JobApplication` class that connects the employee, the job and the service ... you'll probably want to add more information there sooner or later ...  possibilities include things like `created_at`, `confirmed_at`, `confirmed_by` ...

Comment: This is what i don't wanted, but seems like the only possibility...

Comment: I think that your `Service2Job` table should in fact be a 3 way table relationship (with a unique / primary key on `user_id`, `job_id` and `service_id`, and a index on `job_id` and `service_id`)

Comment: @Talus - It is possible, that 2 employees do the same service (e.g. if they are working together) so unique constraint is not a good idea.

Comment: Hence the unique / primary key on the three fields : an employee cannot be in the service / job more than once, right ? If it is 2 employees, then the key is respected. If you want to fetch all the employees for a job and a service, you can do a basic `SELECT employee FROM services2jobs WHERE service_id = ? AND job_id = ?`, hence the index on these two fields.

Comment: @Talus - Yes you are right, my fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a relationship has another references/attributes it is not a relationship anymore, why? because if a relationship needs more references/attributes then it should be handled as model. In you case, you should follow @Talu's advise.

```
Service
 - jobs

Jobs
 - services

Service2Job
 - jobs
 - services
 - employees //this converts your relationship in model

Employees
 - services2jobs
```

Comment: I leaved my database model like it was and followed @nifr's advice and created an extra object to map the service2job attribute, but your statement that this isn't a relationship anymore opened my mind.